# Binding a WPF ComboBox to a List in new Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF...

I am trying to bind a List to a combobox in a new Window.

The List is in the following class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public List<string> ComboBoxItems = new List<string>
    {
        "Item 1", "Item2"
    };
}
```

From MainWindow a new TestWindow is created:

```
private void TestWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var test = new TestClass();
        
    var win = new TestWindow { DataContext = test };
    win.Show();
}
```

In XAML I tried to bind the ComboBoxItems to the ComboBox like:

```
<Window ...
        Title="TestWindow" Height="200" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Name="combo" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxItems}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I thought when I set the DataContext of this new window to an instance of my TestClass, then I have access to its members (including the list ComboBoxItems) and can bind them.

But the ComboBox is empty:

[image: Empty ComboBox]

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

By the way:
In XAML Editor there is no IntelliSense?

[image: Visual Studio XAML Editor]

Any tips for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ComboBoxItems` needs to be a property rather than a field to be the source of DataBinding

```
public List<string> ComboBoxItems { get; } = new List<string>
{
    "Item 1", "Item2"
};
```

Comment: Thank you! In 7 minutes I can accept your answer :D